# Auto generated entity classes in web service

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, webservice-client

I'm working on a little project for school homework. The project consists in a CRUD application for a stationery. We have to do a Web app with JSF (working at 100%), a Java Swing app and C# app, both must call web services operations for CRUD actions.

I'm using Netbeans 7.3.1 as IDE, Glassfish 4.0 as server, PostgreSQL 9.1 as DBMS, JPA for persistency, and EJB3.

I've generated web services from Web project (JSF) doing Right Click, New, Web Service..., Create Web Service from Existing Session Bean.

Also, I've generated Web Service Client in java swing app from Right Click, Web Service Client, From URL, and use my wsdl file url and it worked without problems.

The problem is this didn't generate all entity classes what I need, actually it just generated one of them, that one is of an entity which has a simple map with jpa (You can see this image for reference, the unique class generated is Producto)

[image: Diagram of DB]

Why this could happen? or why should I need to to handle my other object types?

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try in NetBeans IDE 7.3.1

- Add a new connection to PostgreSQL in *Window*, *Services*, *Databases*, *New Connection...*.
- *File*, *New File*, Select you project, in the category Persistence, in File Type, *Entity clases from Database*.

[image]